# Неправильно изменил код

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Ищу точки экстремумов на графике при помощи:

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

n = 15 

df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.V.values, np.less_equal,
                    order=n)[0]]['V']
df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.V.values, np.greater_equal,
                    order=n)[0]]['V']
```

Этот код работает. df.V - просто зачения любые.
Но вот при попытке переписать этот код для работы со списками - выходит не то что надо:

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

n = 15 

v_list = [1,4,6,2,9,1,3,4,3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,3,2,4,3,3,1,6,4,3,5,5,1,4,5,6,7,8,3,2,4,3,3,3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,3,2,4,3,3,1,6,4,5,6,7,8,3,2,4,3,3,3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,3,2,4,3]


mmin = argrelextrema(v_list, np.less_equal, order=n)[0]
mmax= argrelextrema(v_list, np.greater_equal, order=n)[0]
```

Как исправить код выше для работы со списками?

Comment: а что такое `v_list`, и что такое "выходит не то, что надо"?

Comment: попробуйте обернуть v_list в nd.array: v_list = np.array([1,4,6,2,9,1,3,4,...])

Comment: Со списком вообще же ошибка выходит, `argrelextrema` требует на вход `ndarray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да вроде всё у вас работает. Только при `n = 15` пропускает одну из точек из-за слишком широкого "окна" поиска экстремума.

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

n = 15

v_list = np.array([1,4,6,2,9,1,3,4,3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,3,2,4,3,3,1,6,4,3,5,5,1,4,5,6,7,8,3,2,4,3,3,3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,3,2,4,3,3,1,6,4,5,6,7,8,3,2,4,3,3,3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,3,2,4,3])

mmin = argrelextrema(v_list, np.less_equal, order=n)[0]
mmax= argrelextrema(v_list, np.greater_equal, order=n)[0]

plt.plot(np.arange(len(v_list)), v_list)
plt.plot(mmin, v_list[mmin], 'r--o')
plt.plot(mmax, v_list[mmax], 'g--o')
```

[image: extremum15]

Если уменьшить `n` до `10`, то найдёт все экстремумы правильно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Valent Понимаете, у вас в `mmin` индексы значений из `v_list`, а не сами значения. Поэтому `plt.scatter(mmin, v_list[mmin], 'r')` вообще-то работает, я просто нарисовал линии, чтобы понятно было, как выбирается максимум, почему одна из точек не попала в список максимумов.

Comment: Поэтому `mmin` должно быть на оси `x`, а `v_list[mmin]` - на оси `y`, а когда вы пытаетесь рисовать `mmin` по оси `y`, я не очень понимаю, что вы хотите нарисовать таким образом.

Comment: @Valent Ну это же легко: `a = np.zeros_like(v_list)` и затем `a[mmax] = v_list[mmax]`, если я вас правильно понял.